# Laravel Horizon delay between processes

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, horizon

I'm using horizon version 5.10 on redis 2.0 with laravel 8.7. The problem is after a job has been processed, pending jobs don't start immediately.

[Laravel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJqZ2.png)

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vLJB.png)

[horizon config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj6BJ.png)

Jobs are processing immediately with queue work command
`php artisan queue:work`.
Some Processes are delaying almost 1 minute using Laravel Horizon command
`php artisan horizon`.
In Laravel Horizon, how can I run jobs immediately if they still exist?